# How to open files ending with random numbers

Tags: python-2.7, unix

I am collecting data for computational chemistry research. when a program is finished it gives me an output file of format `name.oxxxx` with the x's corresponding the the job number it had when submitted to the cluster I now have hundreds of these and need to pull data from them.

How can I find and open a file that has random numbers on the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done with the [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) function. From the docs:

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
>   according to the rules used by the Unix shell, although results are
>   returned in arbitrary order.

```
In [471]: import glob

In [472]: for file in glob.glob('name.o*'):
     ...:     print(file)
     ...:     
name.o113654829
name.o1234565
name.o1234567
```

You may specify wildcards, and glob will retrieve all files matching this pattern.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for